# Calculation of bowling strike rate

Tags: statistics, cricket

Batting strike rate is calculated as **(No. of runs / No. of balls faced) * 100**. 
How is bowling strike rate calculated?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bowling strike rate is calculated as **total balls bowled / wickets taken** by bowler.

If the bowler has bowled 300 balls and has taken 15 wickets, then the strike rate is
**300/15 = 20**.
This means the bowler has taken 20 balls to take one wicket.

Comment: Does the total balls bowled include wides and no-balls?

Answer (score 5):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strike_rate):

> Bowling strike rate is a measure of how frequently a bowler achieves
>   the primary goal of bowling, namely taking wickets (i.e. getting
>   batsmen out).

and

> Bowling strike rate is defined for a bowler as the average number of
>   balls bowled per wicket taken.

According to [this page](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_calculate_a_bowling_strike_rate_in_cricket):

> A bowlers strike rate is calculated by dividing the number of balls he
>   or she has bowled by the number of wickets taken with those balls.
>
> For example if a bowler has bowled 2000 balls in his career and has
>   taken 50 wickets, he has a bowling strike rate of 40.00. In other
>   words the bowler has taken, on average, a wicket every 40 balls.

Answer (score 2):

It is simply the number of balls bowled divided by the number of wickets taken.

Answer (score 2):

Bowling Strike rate = Number of balls per wicket (Total Balls Bowled/Total Wickets Taken)

Bowling Average = Runs per Wicket (Total Runs Given/Total Wickets Taken)

Answer (score 1):

Practically,
Bowling strike rate = (no. of balls / wickets taken).