# How is a bowler's average calculated?

Tags: cricket, statistics

How is a bowler's **average** calculated?

For an example, [Anil Kumble](http://www.espncricinfo.com/india/content/player/30176.html)'s test-match bowling average is 29.65. What does this number mean?

Comment: I removed the duplicate question. For bowling strike rate see [this question](http://sports.stackexchange.com/q/693/540).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Bowling average = total given runs / wickets taken by bowler**

Let's take an example of Anil Kumble. He has taken 619 wickets and given 18355 runs in Test. So his bowling average = 18355 / 619 = 29.65.

The bowling average indicates the number of runs given by a bowler to take a wicket. So Anil Kumble gave 29.65 runs for every single wicket in Test.